# Post PHP , duplica, triplica, quadriplica registros no Msql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário em php para incluir registros no Mysql, ao enviar o registro duplica triplica as vezes quadriplica registros no mysql, em um tópico vi a sugestão de desabilitar o botão, evitando que o usuário clique sobre o registro mais de uma vez sem querer , tentei fazer esse procedimento, mas mesmo assim os registro as vezes duplicam, será que pode ser alguma coisa com sessão do PHP, percebi que isso ocorre quando tem lentidão na internet.
Segue o código:
pagina do formulario:

```
<!--Formulario de cadastro-->
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" aria-describedby="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>    
    <button type="submit" id="Enviar_cadastro_email" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
<!--JS-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#Enviar_cadastro_email').click(function () {
            $('#Enviar_cadastro_email').prop('disabled', true);
            var vEmail = document.getElementById("Email").value;
            var vPassword = document.getElementById("Password").value;
            var action = "Incluir";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "usuario.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: action,
                        vEmail: vEmail,
                        vPassword: vPassword
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        CarregarListagem();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<!--PHP - back -->
<?php
include "../confi.php";
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
     if ($_POST["action"] == "Incluir") {
        $statement = $connection->prepare("
          INSERT INTO usuario (
            usuario_email,
            usuario_senha
          )
          VALUES( 
            :usuario_email,
            :usuario_senha
          )
          ");
        $result = $statement->execute(
                array(
                    ':usuario_email'=> $_POST["vEmail"],
                    ':usuario_senha'=> $_POST["vPassword"]
                )
        );
        if (!empty($result)) {
            echo 'Usuário inserido com sucesso!';
        } else {
            echo 'Erro ao inserir usuário!';
        }
    }
}
```

esse é o meu código

Comment: Se você colocar uma validação antes da inserção no banco, que verifica se os dados já existem, para só aí enviar, o problema continua? Normalmente, na própria configuração do banco, crio chaves únicas onde não quero que um dado se repita, assim, ainda que o código por qualquer motivo, "tente" duplicar, o próprio banco de dados vai rejeitar a inserção. Se for viável alterar o Banco de Dados, dá uma olhada em `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Um palpite, suponho que o botão `Enviar` esteja disparando dois eventos submit. Aqui `<button type="submit"` troque para `<button type="button"` e veja se para de duplicar a inserção de  registros.

Answer (score 0):

Antes na minha tabela estava Auto increment , logo removi e agora faço uma consulta no banco de dados pra pegar o ultimo registro, e não deixa incluir sem o codigo.
Tambem segui a orientação do colega de alterar

```
if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 'Usuário inserido com sucesso!';
    } else {
        echo 'Erro ao inserir usuário!';
    }
```

para

```
if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo $connection->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        echo 'Erro ao alterar o registro';
    }
```

sendo assim, o meu problema foi resolvido

Answer (score -4):

```
<?php
    include "../confi.php";
    if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
        if ($_POST["action"] == "Incluir") {
        $sql = "  INSERT INTO usuario ( usuario_email, usuario_senha)  VALUES(?,?)";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindvalue(1, $_POST["vEmail"]);
        $statement->bindvalue(2, $_POST["vPassword"]);

        $statement->execute();

        if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo 'Usuário inserido com sucesso!';
        } else {
            echo 'Erro ao inserir usuário!';
        }
      }
    }
```

usei aqui `bindvalue`, explicando um pouco do `bindvalue`:
primeiro parâmetro vem a posição do `bindvalue`
segundo parâmetro a informação que ira substituir o `bindvalue`.
`bindvalue` é o ponto de interrogação "?"

Comment: Testei aqui Lucas ... mas mesmo assim continua inserindo os registros

Comment: alterei o código, olha se da certo agora

Comment: Ainda continua ocorrendo o erro